# REST Api Get method to catch value of a column in one list and present it in another's list column in new form

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, custom-list, newform

I have two lists, list1 with coulmn1.1 which is number column.
I want list1 column1 value to catch and show in list2 column2.1 on new form.

```
<script src="http://sitename/SiteAssets/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
  url: " http://sitename/_api/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('ListName1')/items?$filter='NameOfColumn1.1',
             type: "GET",
             headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
             success: function(data) {
              var data = data.d;
              /* Part which I don't know*/
              },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(xhr));        }
         });
  });
```

If you could explain me what should I add or edit in code so it can be workable.

Comment: You want the to take the column value of the List 1 and use as a filter in the List 2?

Comment: no. I want to show that column in list2's new form

Comment: Ok, but you have more than one item in the list1? Wich item is going to be shown in the newform of the list 2?

Comment: Sorry on my incomplete question. Based on user who is opening new form in list2 I want to catch column1 from list1. More detail in list1 I have items based on users (each user has it's item) and when one of them creates new item in list2 I want to show column1 from list1.

Comment: Right, another question, the column that has the user is a person/people column?